# Java method overload

Tags: java

I have 2 alternatives to implement a calculation method, and I am wondering what would be the better approach.

The method needs some int and double parameters and (in some cases) a special flag to do some different calculation.

In the first example, I could call the method with 'calculateFoo(1, 2.0d)' to have the boolean flag == FALSE.

In the second example, I always have to set the boolean flag (even if I do not need it)

Method 1: (here I'm using the '...' as an 'method overloading' parameter)

```
public SomeObject calculateFoo(int pIntValue, double pDoubleValue, boolean... pDoSpecialStuff) {

    if (pDoSpecialStuff.length == 0 || pDoSpecialStuff[0] == false) {
        // method was called without boolean flag or boolean flag was set to FALSE

        // do some calculation stuff
        // ...
    } else {
        // method was called with boolean flag == TRUE

        // do some other calculation stuff
        // ...
    }

    return SomeObject; 
}
```

Method 2: (this is the 'common' approach)

```
public SomeObject calculateFoo(int pIntValue, double pDoubleValue, boolean pDoSpecialStuff) {

    if (pDoSpecialStuff == false) {
        // method was called with boolean flag == FALSE

        // do some calculation stuff
        // ...
    } else {
        // method was called with boolean flag == TRUE

        // do some other calculation stuff
        // ...
    }

    return SomeObject; 
}
```

Comment: Instead of using flags to determine "what to do" you should have multiple methods - one method - one action. It's object-oriented approach. Flags are generally ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following pattern:

```
public ResultType calcFoo( int i, double d ) {
    return calc( i, d, false );
}

public ResultType calcFoo( int i, double d, boolean flag ) {
    if( flag ) {
        ...
        return result;
    }
    else {
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Generally it's better to use an enum instead of a boolean flag. It makes your code more readable and is just as fast.

I noticed you considered using varargs. If you want to use more flags consider using an EnumSet to pass a set of flags to the method. If you want to pass 0 or 1 flags, varargs is even more definitely an antipattern.

Answer (score 2):

both your methods have code smell, boolean flags suck

here is my suggestion

```
public SomeObject calculateFoo(int pIntValue, double pDoubleValue) {
    // normal calculation here 
}

public SomeObject calculateFooSpecial(int pIntValue, double pDoubleValue) {
    // special calculation here 
}
```

Comment: +1, and both methods could call a third, private method which contains code common to both calculations

Answer (score 1):

Do the second variant as it is more explicit. Varargs would allow you to pass more than one boolean which are then not used. Better you explicitly define the interface using a single boolean.

If you want to have a default for the boolean flag use another overload:

```
public SomeObject calculateFoo(int pIntValue, double pDoubleValue) {
   return calculateFoo(pIntValue, pDoubleValue, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define another one method with just two parameter to perform default calculation.

```
public SomeObject calcFoo(int, double) {
    ....
}

public SomeObject calcFoo(int i, double d, boolean b) {
    if(b) {
        ....
    } else {
        return calcFoo(i, d);
    }
}
```